# How to identify the most common category referencing the same element?

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, math

I have two relations: `Location(category,item)` and `Item(item)`

Each item *can* be listed under multiple categories.

What SQL query can be used in figuring out which two categories, from `Location(category,item)` most frequently contain the same item?

*note: I am looking for a SQL statement but I tagged this question as algorithm / math, as I am willing to accept a solution in the form of an algorithm in case a SQL query can not be provided.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in SQL with `join` and `group by`.  Join the `location` table to itself on `item`, then count the matches.  Order by this descending and choose the first one, if you want the pair with the most matches:

```
select l1.category, l2.category, count(*) as cnt
from location l1 join
     location l2
     on l1.item = l2.item and
        l1.category < l2.category
group by l1.category, l2.category
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Note that this assumes that `category, item` is unique in `location`.  Otherwise, you can use this `select`:

```
select l1.category, l2.category, count(distinct l1.item) as cnt
```

Comment: .id should have been .item I cannot edit since I must edit atleast 6 characters. Thanks, your solution works!